# How can I make the materialUI drawer scroll to bottom after a refresh? in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Material UI Drawer with lots of checkboxes and radio buttons for an advanced search page. Each and every checkbox or radio click mutates the API get request for a "on-the-fly" results without the need to click a submit button. My problem is that every time this happens, because there is a refresh happening, the drawer resets back top the top.

I have all of my radio buttons at at the bottom so if I could at least force those click events for the radio buttons to scroll my drawer to the bottom, that would make it look like it preserved the scroll position.

```
function scrollToBottom() {
    let height = document.getElementById('customAdvancedDrawer').clientHeight;
    
    const drawerEl = document.getElementById('customAdvancedDrawer').getScrollElement();
      
    drawerEl.scrollTop = height; //Is there such a thing as .scrollBottom?
}
```

I tried the function above but it doesn't work and I'm getting an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getScrollElement')`. I'm assuming that the drawer is not mounted when this fires?

I'm calling the function in the onChange event

```
<CustomRadioGroup 
    className="preventJumpToTop"
    radiodata={selectors.regions} 
    radiovalues={state.region} 
    defaultValue={state.region} 
    handleOnRadioChange={(value) =>  {
       setState({ ...state, region: value }); 
       scrollToBottom()
    }} 
    radiolabel="Region" />
```

EDIT-

I added a codesandbox below. It may make it more confusing since the whole thing is about a scroll position, which means I have to add a lot of radio and checkbox controls to make the drawer linger than the viewport. Plus a lot of other dependencies too. ***Use the SortingMetrics radio buttons to test it***. The others will break because there is no API call attached.

[**CODESANDBOX**](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-pond-y12pjr)

Thanks in advance

**MORE EDITS**
I tried adding an ID to the drawer paper and the content in it so that I can get the height of the content itself which it's longer than the drawer and then set the scroll on the drawer to the clientHeight of the content. Still nothing. Please HALP!!! lol

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
  const drawerPaper = document.getElementById('customAdvancedDrawer');
  const drawerBox = document.getElementById('advancedDrawerBox');
  let clientHeight = drawerBox.clientHeight;

  drawerPaper.scrollTo({
    top: clientHeight,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
  drawerPaper.scroll(0, clientHeight);
  console.log("clientHeight: ", clientHeight);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new)?

Comment: @RubenSmn I edited my question with a codesandbox. It may make it more confusing since the whole thing is about a scroll position, which means I have to add a lot of radio and checkbox controls to make the drawer linger than the viewport. Plus a lot of other dependencies too. Use the SortingMetrics radio buttons to test it. The others will break because there is no API call attached. `https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-pond-y12pjr`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're defining your `FilterDrawer` inside your `App` component it will make a **new reference** when a state changes causing a re-render of the whole drawer. To avoid this you can create a seperate component.

```js
function FilterDrawer({ advanceddraweropen, setAdvancedDrawerOpen }) {
  // ... your states
  return (
    <AdvancedFilterDrawer
      id="customAdvancedDrawer"
      opendrawer={advanceddraweropen}
      handleClose={handleAdvDrawerClose}
    >
      // all the radio etc...
    </AdvancedFilterDrawer>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [advanceddraweropen, setAdvancedDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleAdvDrawerOpen = () => {
    setAdvancedDrawerOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      // ...
      <CustomDrawer
        advanceddraweropen={advanceddraweropen}
        setAdvancedDrawerOpen={setAdvancedDrawerOpen}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

This way it only updates the checkbox / radio where a value changes. No need for the `scrollToBottom` functionality.

If you render your fetch results within the `App` component simply by mapping over them, the same problem will occur there. I recommend to create a component which takes in the results and let that component handle the rendering of the results. This way the whole `App` component does not get re-rendered but just the 'list' .

Comment: Separating the states was a nice touch. I can't believe I didn't do that lol. But unfortunately, it didn't change anything

Comment: It works in the sandbox, but when you have GET requests being fired on the each of those onChange event listeners for the on-the-fly effect, a refresh is triggered

Comment: @LOTUSMS if you render your fetch results within the `App` component simply by mapping over them, it might be the same problem there. I recommend to create a component which takes in the results and let that component handle the rendering of the results.

Comment: Isolating the functionality in a separate rendering component was the ticket!! Thank you! Add that to the answer so I can mark it